# Using DIV to pop up a new window

Tags: html, popup, window

I wanted to ask you the following question. How can  I use DIV to pop up a new window?

```
<div class="ty-social-link-block"><h3 class="ty-social-link__title"> 
{__("get_social")}</h3>

<div class="ty-social-link facebook">
<a href="http://www.facebook.com"><i class="ty-icon-facebook"></i>    
Facebook</a>
</div>


<div class="ty-social-link twitter">
<a href="https://twitter.com"><i class="ty-icon-twitter"></i> Twitter</a>
</div></div>
```

I want to use this code to pop Facebook and Twitter in a new separate window, please help me!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

using only html, add `target="_blank"` attribute in your `<a>` tags:

```
<div class="ty-social-link-block"><h3 class="ty-social-link__title"> 
{__("get_social")}</h3>

<div class="ty-social-link facebook">
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="ty-icon-facebook"></i>    
Facebook</a>
</div>

<div class="ty-social-link twitter">
<a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank"><i class="ty-icon-twitter"></i> Twitter</a>
</div></div>
```

Comment: This didn't help me, I added it to the code of the website but it still doesn't do anything... I am using CS Cart platform and I am trying to figure out how to make a whole new Chrome / Mozilla / IE ... window to pop up as soon as you hit the button where that code is attached to

Comment: `target="_blank"` should open in a new window or new tab, if your browser does not override it and forces same window, if you are looking for js solution, say it.